# Efficiently converting strings to appropriate numeric types in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm dealing with pandas DataFrames in which columns may contain strings representing numbers, may contain unexpected non-numeric characters, and the numbers represented by the strings may be of float or int type. For example, the DataFrame may contain something like "$625,452,242.95" for a float of 625452242.95 or "53.000.395" for an int equal to 53000395. The DataFrames are being read from a CSV file, and may be quite large.

What is the most efficient way to convert all such strings in a DataFrame to the appropriate numeric types? Thank you.

Comment: How do you know 53.000.395 is 53000395 but not 53000.395?

Comment: A person could infer that (perhaps not always reliably) from looking at the rest of the values in the CSV, or by reading the associated meta data. However, I'd like an approach that doesn't go that far, and only looks at each value individually, so I'd settle for treating a rightmost period as a decimal point, and anything to the left of that being treated as a comma would be in a numeric context.

Answer (score 5):

You can also try to replace those symbols and separator:

```
In [27]: df = pd.DataFrame([['$1,111'], ['$2,222']])

In [28]: df
Out[28]: 
        0
0  $1,111
1  $2,222

In [29]: df[0] = df[0].str.replace(r'[$,]', '').astype('float')

In [30]: df
Out[30]: 
      0
0  1111
1  2222
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the [read_csv documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html).

- If all the thousands separators are decimals, use `thousands='.'`.
- For a column with money, write a function that chops off the $ and converts the remaining string into an integer or a float. Pass it to `read_csv` via `converters`. (Again, see docs.)

I expect any custom converters will be slow -- read_csv is ruthlessly optimized in C -- so use built-in features (e.g., the `thousands` keyword) wherever possible.

Comment: Warning: thousands sep doesn't work in 0.12 (and possibly before) https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4322.